# AWS serverless projects cannot be shared via Git?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, serverless-framework

`s-function.json` needs that variable `"customRole": "${myLambdaRole}",`

BUT if somebody else get my `serverless project` via `git clone` he doesn't get the `_meta` folder.

Now he calls `serverless project init` with the same stage and region. That creates the `_meta` folder BUT it does NOT populate the `s-variables-common.json` with the `Output Variables` from `s-resources-cf.json`.

Now he tries to deploy with `serverless dash deploy` and that errors

```
Serverless: WARNING: This variable is not defined: myLambdaRole
```

Unfortunately even calling `serverless resources deploy` will not fix the problem because it says

```
Serverless: Deploying resources to stage "dev" in region "us-east-1" via Cloudformation (~3 minutes)...  
Serverless: No resource updates are to be performed.
```

and the `s-variables-common.json` is still not populated with the necessary output variables.

What that means is basically that it is impossible to work as a team together at the same stage in the same region with the same resources when sharing the project via `Git`.

So since we don't want to check in the `_meta` folder into `Git` I would suggest that a `serverless project init` call should make sure that all the `Output Variables` are properly fetched and populated in the `s-variables-common.json`.

This is pretty important, or how do you guys share projects via 'Git' ?

Comment: Might be better to raise this as an issue with the serverless project here: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues especially if you are requesting changes to the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin called "meta sync" that should solve your problem:
https://github.com/serverless/serverless-meta-sync

Comment: Thanks, we are testing the meta-sync at the moment to see if it works in a big enterprise situation with hundreds of developers.